# Calculate a duration of a deal when all tasks within that deal are closed in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'START DATE': ['01/01/2023', '01/01/2023', '01/20/2023', '01/22/2023', '01/13/2023', '01/12/2023'],
    'END DATE': ['01/10/2023', '01/15/2023', '01/23/2023', '01/24/2023', '01/14/2023', '01/13/2023'],
    'DEAL': ['D1', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D4'],
    'TASK': ['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5', 'T6'],
    'STATUS': ['Closed', 'Closed', 'Open', 'Closed', 'Open', 'Closed']
})
```

I need to create a new column `'DURATION'`, which will calculate business days when the `DEAL` is closed. Note that the `DEAL` is considered closed **only if all tasks of that deal are closed**.

The sultion could be also creating a new dataframe with results as follows:

| START DATE | END DATE | DEAL | STATUS | DURATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 01/15/2023 | D1 | Closed | 10 |
| 01/22/2023 | 01/24/2023 | D3 | Closed | 1 |

This is my code so far but is not working:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'START DATE': ['01/01/2023', '01/01/2023', '01/20/2023', '01/22/2023', '01/13/2023', '01/12/2023'],
    'END DATE': ['01/10/2023', '01/15/2023', '01/23/2023', '01/24/2023', '01/14/2023', '01/13/2023'],
    'DEAL': ['D1', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D4'],
    'TASK': ['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5', 'T6'],
    'STATUS': ['Closed', 'Closed', 'Open', 'Closed', 'Open', 'Closed']
})

# convert date columns to datetime format
df['START DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START DATE'])
df['END DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['END DATE'])

# group by DEAL and check if all tasks are closed
closed_deals = df.groupby('DEAL').apply(lambda x: all(x['STATUS'] == 'Closed')).reset_index(drop=True)

# calculate duration for closed deals
duration = df[closed_deals]['END DATE'].max() - df[closed_deals]['START DATE'].min()

# merge duration back to original dataframe
df = pd.merge(df, duration, on='DEAL', how='left')
df = df.rename(columns={0: 'DURATION'})

df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can groupby `DEAL` and analyze each case. Then create a new dataframe with the results:

```
df["START DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["START DATE"])
df["END DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["END DATE"])

groups_data_list = []
for name, group in df.groupby("DEAL",group_keys=False):
    group_data = {}
    if (group.STATUS == "Closed").all():
        group_data["START DATE"] = group["START DATE"].min()
        group_data["END DATE"] = group["END DATE"].max()
        group_data["DEAL"] = group["DEAL"].unique()[0]
        group_data["STATUS"] = group["STATUS"].unique()[0]
        group_data["DURATION"] = len(pd.bdate_range(start=group_data["START DATE"], end=group_data["END DATE"]))
        groups_data_list.append(group_data)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(groups_data_list)
```

|  | START DATE | END DATE | DEAL | STATUS | DURATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-15 | D1 | Closed | 10 |
| 1 | 2023-01-22 | 2023-01-24 | D3 | Closed | 2 |

Note: the duration in business days for `D3` is 2, I've checked the calendar.

EDIT: I've found that in `np.busday_count()` the results for `D3` is 1. I don't know why the difference between libraries, maybe the calendar they're using is different. If you want to use the `np` library you can do the following:

```
df["START DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["START DATE"])
df["END DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["END DATE"])

groups_data_list = []
for name, group in df.groupby("DEAL",group_keys=False):
    group_data = {}
    if (group.STATUS == "Closed").all():
        group_data["START DATE"] = group["START DATE"].min()
        group_data["END DATE"] = group["END DATE"].max()
        group_data["DEAL"] = group["DEAL"].unique()[0]
        group_data["STATUS"] = group["STATUS"].unique()[0]
        groups_data_list.append(group_data)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(groups_data_list)
new_df["DURATION"] = np.busday_count(new_df['START DATE'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'), 
                                     new_df['END DATE'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'))
```

|  | START DATE | END DATE | DEAL | STATUS | DURATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | D1 | Closed | 10 |
| 1 | 2023-01-22 00:00:00 | 2023-01-24 00:00:00 | D3 | Closed | 1 |

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

```
# change the dtype to datetime
df['START DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START DATE'])
df['END DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['END DATE'])

# Create a boolean mask to identify rows where
# STATUS is Closed in all rows for each DEAL
df['flag'] = df['STATUS'] == 'Closed'
mask = df.groupby('DEAL')['flag'].transform('all')

# Filter the rows using the boolean mask then group the dataframe
# by DEAL and aggregate start using min and end using max
df1 = (
    df[mask]
    .groupby('DEAL', as_index=False)
    .agg({'START DATE': min, 'END DATE': max, 'STATUS': 'first'})
)

# calculate the busyday count using numpy's builtin function
df1['DURATION'] = np.busday_count(df1['START DATE'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'), 
                                  df1['END DATE'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'))
```

#### Result

```
  DEAL START DATE   END DATE  STATUS  DURATION
0   D1 2023-01-01 2023-01-15  Closed        10
1   D3 2023-01-22 2023-01-24  Closed         1
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
#cONVERT STR TO DATEtime
df["START DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["START DATE"])
df["END DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["END DATE"])

#Creating new dataframe only with DEAL which have all task cloased
#Second, groupedBy Deal and selected min startD and max endD accordingly
d = df[df['DEAL'].apply(lambda x: all([i=='Closed' for i in df[(df['DEAL']==x
       )]['STATUS'].tolist()]))].groupby('DEAL').agg({'START DATE':[min] ,'END DATE':[max]}
       ).reset_index()

#removing the extra column received via groupBy
d.columns = d.columns.droplevel(1)

#Adding new column which says the working days duration of SD and ED
d['Duration'] = d.apply(lambda r: np.busday_count(r['START DATE'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                                        r['END DATE'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) ,axis=1)

d
```